# python troubles on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, update-manager

after a system updates I having troubles with a python based Apps
The [Updater-manager](http://s12.postimg.org/4sug1zy25/Captura_de_pantalla_de_2013_08_09_00_03_32.png) doesn't download the updates packages, and I realized this python trobles because I use flexget for RSS downloading, which is Python based, and when I run it it return:

```
~$ flexget
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flexget", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

if I run pip, a Python script, it returns:

```
$ sudo pip install flexget
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

everything points to this line: "from pkg_resources import load_entry_point"

in flexget I found this: http://flexget.com/wiki/PipProblems

but reinstalling Python didn't solved the trouble
how could it be fixed

Comment: Please click the tick symbol next to your answer to accept your answer.  That is how we mark a thread as closed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ok I solved it. first of all I installed python-setuptools from synaptic, then I run from the termnial a python depency App, and then I got this [image: return]

then I run this as root:

```
pip install setuptools==0.7
```